# VBA - Merging cells with the same data and copying format across row to specific columns

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating an excel sheet to handle a schedule I use on a daily basis. The data is sent as a CSV and then copied over as raw data.

I would like a VBA option to format the cells automatically where the values all match. (see images)
***Raw Data copied in***
[image: Raw Data copied in]

***Format id like to apply with VBA***
[image: Format id like to apply with VBA]

I can get the cells to merge when the values are the same using this code:

```
Sub MergeSameCells()
    
    'turn off display alerts while merging
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    'specify range of cells for merging
    Set myRange = Range("A1:A1000")

    'merge all same cells in range
MergeSame:
    For Each cell In myRange
        If cell.Value = cell.Offset(1, 0).Value And Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
            Range(cell, cell.Offset(1, 0)).Merge
            cell.VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
            GoTo MergeSame
        End If
    Next
    
    'turn display alerts back on
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

But where I run into issues is Column E (#5) where a lot of the values are the same but are for different routes. Is there a way to either Merge based on the first column and then copy to specific columns, or a way to merge certain cells based on the values in column A (#1).

In short I want to click a button and have the formatting in the second picture be applied.

Comment: Please **edit your question** to post your data as text that can be copy/paste3d as it appears in a ***Text Editor*** (not in Excel). Just copy/paste the data from the Text Editor, and format it as Code (or leave it and someone will format it for you). See [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, it's just a matter of merging when columns 1,2,3 and 5 are identical.

- Collect the rows to be merged into a dictionary

  - Key is a concatenation of columns 1,2,3,5 (or whichever you want to compare
  - Item stored is a collection of the row numbers to be merged

```
'set reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime
Option Explicit
Sub FormatData()
    Dim rRng As Range, c As Range
    Dim vSrc As Variant, vKey As Variant
    Dim LR As Long, LC As Long
    Dim dDict As Dictionary, col As Collection
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, K As Long, v As Variant, O As Object
    Dim MergeCols As Variant
    
MergeCols = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
    
    
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    LR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LC = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set rRng = Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LR, LC))
    vSrc = rRng 'Do cell contents comparisons in VBA array for speed considerations
End With

'Test if merge exists
    For Each c In rRng.Columns(1).Cells
        If c.MergeCells = True Then
            MsgBox "Already Merged"
            Exit Sub
       End If
    Next c

Set dDict = New Dictionary
    dDict.CompareMode = TextCompare 'Case insensitive
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(vSrc)
        'create key from MergeCols
        vKey = ""
        For j = 0 To UBound(MergeCols)
            vKey = vKey & "|" & vSrc(i, MergeCols(j))
        Next j
        
        If Not dDict.Exists(vKey) Then
            Set col = New Collection
            col.Add i
            dDict.Add Key:=vKey, Item:=col
        Else
            dDict(vKey).Add i
        End If
    Next i
    
'Merge Cells and format the cells
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each v In dDict.Keys
    Set O = dDict(v)
        For j = 0 To UBound(MergeCols)
            Set c = rRng(RowIndex:=O(1), columnindex:=MergeCols(j)).Resize(Rowsize:=O(O.Count) - O(1) + 1)
            With c
                .Merge
                .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            End With
        Next j
Next v
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

***Before***
[image]

***After***
[image]

Comment: Thank you, That might be just what I am looking for, but I need to merge cells in columns: 1,2,3,4,5,6,8,14,15,16,17,18,19,20. I also ran the code above and got Compile Error: User-defined type not defined.

Comment: @JohnWhite With regard to the error, did you comply with the code comment at the beginning and set the reference? If you did, what line is showing the error? To add additional columns to be considered in determining whether you have duplicates, merely modify the code as I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Hiya, when I run it highlights "dDict As Dictionary" then when I click okay on the alert it highlights "Sub FormatData()" in Yellow. 
Copied it right over as it was. Set the reference?

Comment: @JohnWhite At the top menu of the VBE, navigate to `Tools=>References` and select the reference mentioned. Or, if this is going to be distributed, you can use late-binding. Do a search for the differences between late and early binding. I generally prefer early binding as you get the advantage of intellisense and more easily understood object names. Also it is a bit faster. But for distributed code, it can be a PITA.

Comment: Thank you, I added the reference and got it to work once. Then I rearranged a few of the columns and figured if I change the numbers in ' vKey = vSrc(I, 1) & vSrc(I, 2) & vSrc(I, 3) & vSrc(I, 5)' it would work, and it didn't. If I wanted to make it work to merge columns 1,2,3,4,5,7,17,18,19,20,22 and not the others (whether filled or blank) would this be possible? Also, if I needed to add 10 rows above the column titles so the data to be merged starts at row 12, would this be possible. :-)

Comment: @JohnWhite You have to change both `vKey` and also the columns you are merging. Yes. And yes.

Comment: @JohnWhite Code edited to show a method to enter an array of all the columns to be checked for the merge to occur.  See the `MergeCols`  array set near the beginning, and used further down to construct `vKey` and also determine what is merged.